# how to calculate height of elements inside a div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div which contains number of elements which user can drag and drop to rearrange inside. Also, he can add new elements from tool bar. I want to increase height of outer div to wrap all those elements. Now they overlap on footer. The challenges I fighting with are - 
1. How to find elements which are placed below other. All the elements are have relative positions.
2. Change of height needs to be handled on drop of an element.

I need solution very urgently.

Thanks

Comment: what have u done so far?..let us see html and codes written ..

Comment: The browser should handle this...why isn't it?  You have to have some explicit styling in place that the outer div doesn't *already* stretch to it's contents, can you post that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var height = 0;
$("div > *").each(function () {
  height += $(this).height();
})
```

Comment: I prefer `var totalHeight = 0;
$("#container").children().each(function(){
    totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
});
alert("Total Height: " + totalHeight + "px");`1) I avoid naming variables that match attribute names 2) outerHeight takes padding, margins and borders into consideration

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the `Array.prototype.reduce` method to simplify the solution into a single line:

```
        var innerHeight = $("#parentDIV").children().reduce(function(a, b){
            return $(a).height() + $(b).height(); 
        });
```

The reduce method is useful in general, and it is supported by *most* modern browsers. To ensure compatibility, you can easily add the method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

Best way I think is this:

for the first create elements for div

```
var divToShow = " < div id='addNEWpop' > ";
```

then put all your elements in it, then append it to your body

```
$(document.body).append(divToShow);
```

now lets get height of div

```
heightS=$('[id^="addNEWpop"]').height();
```

before you show it make css

```
$("#addNEWpop").css({width:"400px",height:heightS+"px",display: "none", })
```

and finally

```
$('[id^="addNEWpop"]').show("slow");
```